# Как определить площадь треугольника по его координатам?

Tags: python, python-3.x, геометрия

Задача состоит в следующем: вводится 6 чисел – координаты трёх вершин треугольника. Необходимо найти его площадь. В тестирующей системе этот код не проходит 1 тест. В чем косяк не знаю. Python 3.3

Входные данные:

Шесть чисел – координаты трёх вершин треугольника.

Выходные данные:

Одно число – величина площади треугольника.

Примеры

входные данные:

1 1 2 4 3 2

выходные данные:

2.50000

Насчет точности вычислений и округления в условии ничего не сказано, пробовал по-разному, не помогло.

```
import math

x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 = list(map(int, input().split()))
a = math.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)
b = math.sqrt((x3 - x1) ** 2 + (y3 - y1) ** 2)
c = math.sqrt((x2 - x3) ** 2 + (y2 - y3) ** 2)
p = (a + b + c) / 2
res = math.sqrt(p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c))
print(res)
```

Comment: пример теста, особенности ввода-вывода, и точность вычислений проверьте.

Comment: добавьте в вопрос входные данные и результат

Comment: формула какая-то слишком сложная... по-моему можно без корней и квадратов обойтись...

Comment: res = [(x2-x1)(y3-y1) - (y2-y1)(x3-x1)]/2

Comment: `A = abs( x1*(y2 - y3) + x2*(y3 - y1)  +  x3*(y1 - y2) ) / 2.0`

Comment: @MaxU Ваша формула зашла, спасибо.

Comment: @Никита, я проверил Вашу формулу, она тоже отрабатывает корректно с такими данными `x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 = [1,1,2,4,3,2]`. Это формула Герона, если что. Может у Вас ошибка во входных параметрах `list(map(int, input().split()))`? У меня на эту строку ругается, что передан не итерируемый объект.

Comment: @AlexKrass Я имел ввиду, что программа не прошла один тест(входные данные на нем неизвестны), а не тот тест, который в условии. Если ругается, возможно у Вас другая версия питона.

Comment: @Никита, сначала я проверил на python 2, сейчас еще на python 3, там вывод был интереснее: `2.5000000000000013`, [вот ссылка](https://goo.gl/zjvvD7) Может в этом дело, но Ваш код написан с виду правильно.

Comment: @AlexKrass дело не в этом, загонял и с округлением, и без.

Comment: Ладно, это так, предположения высказал ради интереса. Все равно без знания, какие конкретно тесты проводятся, это превращается в гадание. @MaxU, не хотите оформить как ответ, если уж код помог автору?

Comment: @AlexKrass думаю, что скорее всего дело в погрешности вычислений в этой формуле, т. к. там квадратные корни.

Comment: @AlexKrass, оформил как ответ, хотя сомневаюсь, что это может кому-нибудь еще пригодиться... ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте воспользоваться [другой формулой](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordtrianglearea.html):

```
x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 = map(int, input().split())
A = abs( x1*(y2 - y3) + x2*(y3 - y1) + x3*(y1 - y2) ) / 2.0
print(A)
```

Тест:

```
In [22]: x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 = list(map(int, input().split()))
1 1 2 4 3 2

In [23]: A = abs( x1*(y2 - y3) + x2*(y3 - y1) + x3*(y1 - y2) ) / 2.0

In [24]: print(A)
2.5
```

PS в [этом ответе](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516219/finding-out-the-area-of-a-triangle-if-the-coordinates-of-the-three-vertices-are) есть и другие формулы нахождения площади треугольника при заданных координатах вершин  ([спасибо @jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/622727/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc/622736?noredirect=1#comment867608_622736))

Comment: Неплохо бы написать, откуда она, такая красивая, берется.

Comment: @Igor, первая ссылка в гугле: https://www.google.com/search?q=triangle+area+by+coordinates&pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr ;-)

Comment: а-а-а, из `Google` :). Я надеялся на "векторное произведение".

Comment: Другие формулы: [Finding out the area of a triangle if the coordinates of the three vertices are given](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/516219/1665)

Comment: @jfs, спасибо, добавил в ответ.

Comment: нет там "других формул". Во всех ответах варианты одной и той же - как и Ваша.

Comment: @Igor, по большому счету да, но мне например понравился вариант с матрицей, который позволяет легко запомнить формулу...

Comment: @MaxU Увы мне, увы.

Comment: @Igor если под "одной и той же", вы имеете ввиду что при точном вычислении они одинаковый результат дают, то это конечно тривиально корректно (иначе неправильные формулы были бы). Если вы думаете, что нет разницы между формулами в разных ответах, то это опять таки тривиально неверно—разница визуальна видна (что может проявляться, к примеру, при вычислениях с плавающей точкой или с конечными int, что может  к разным результатам вести).

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас есть два вектора V1(x1, y1) и V2(x2, y2), то величина

S<sub>параллелограм</sub> = x1 * y2 - x2 * y1

даст вам знаковую площадь параллелограмма, построенного на этих векторах. (Знак этой величины будет определять направление "заметания" плоскости от вектора V1 к вектору V2 - по часовой или против часовой стрелки.) А если разделить эту площадь на 2, то, очевидно, получится знаковая площадь треугольника, образованного этими векторами.

Таким образом, если в вашем случае имеются координаты вершин A(xa, ya), B(xb, yb) и C(xc, yc), вы можете выбрать AB за V1 и AC за V2 и получить

S<sub>треугольник</sub> = | (xb - xa) * (yc - ya) - (xc - xa) * (yb - ya) | / 2

Выбор сторон для векторов в данном случае произволен и результат от него не зависит.

На ваших входных данных:

S<sub>треугольник</sub> = | (2 - 1) * (2 - 1) - (3 - 1) * (4 - 1) | / 2 = 5 / 2 = 2.5

Несложно видеть, что эта формула также является частным случаем общей [формулы Гаусса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8_%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0) (ака "формула шнуровки") для площади *произвольного* многоугольника. Точнее, скорее вывод формулы Гаусса опирается на эту формулу знаковой площади "элементарного" треугольника.